# What is wrong with my code near "generate fulladder" (Error: module is not defined)?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm writing in SystemVerilog, and I'm attempting to make a n-bit look-ahead adder. I have issues with `generate`; I get the following errors:

```
** Error: design.sv(13): Module 'fulladder' is not defined.
#  For instance 'f0' at path 'carry_lookahead_adder_tb.carry_lookahead_inst'
# ** Error: design.sv(17): Module 'fulladder' is not defined.
#  For instance 'fi' at path 'carry_lookahead_adder_tb.carry_lookahead_inst.f_loop'
# ** Error: design.sv(17): Module 'fulladder' is not defined.
#  For instance 'fi' at path 'carry_lookahead_adder_tb.carry_lookahead_inst.f_loop'
# Optimization failed
```

Line 13 is `fulladder f0`...

```
module carry_lookahead_adder
  #(parameter WIDTH=32)
  (input logic [WIDTH-1:0] i_add1,
   input logic [WIDTH-1:0] i_add2,
   output logic [WIDTH:0] o_result
  );
  logic [WIDTH:0]  w_C;
  logic [WIDTH-1:0] w_G, w_P, w_SUM;
  
  //Generate full adders
  genvar i;
  fulladder f0 (i_bit1(i_add1[0]), i_bit2(i_add2[0]),i_carry(w_C[0]), o_sum(w_SUM[0]), o_carry());
  generate for (i= 1; i<WIDTH; i++)
    begin : f_loop   
      
      fulladder fi
      (i_bit1(i_add1[i]),
        i_bit2(i_add2[i]),
        i_carry(w_C[i]),
        o_sum(w_SUM[i]),
        o_carry()
      );
    end 
  endgenerate
  
  genvar jj;
  generate 
    for (jj=0; jj<WIDTH; jj++)
      begin
        assign w_G[jj]  = i_add1[jj] & i_add2[jj];
        assign w_P[jj]  = i_add1[jj] | i_add2[jj];
        assign w_C[jj+1] = w_G[jj] | (w_P[jj] & w_C[jj]);
      end
  endgenerate     
    
      assign w_C[0] = 1'b0; //No carry input
     
  assign o_result = {w_C[WIDTH], w_SUM};
                                          
endmodule
```

I know I'm creating/calling the function wrong, but I can't find any good resources on how to do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors have nothing to do with the `generate` construct.  The errors are simply telling you that the `fulladder` module is not defined.  This means that you did not include the module when you compiled your Verilog code.

Note that the 1st error message refers to instance `f0` which is not inside the `generate`.  I get the same error message when I run your code on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/BFyh) with all of the `generate` code removed:

```
module carry_lookahead_adder
  #(parameter WIDTH=32)
  (input logic [WIDTH-1:0] i_add1,
   input logic [WIDTH-1:0] i_add2,
   output logic [WIDTH:0] o_result
  );
  logic [WIDTH:0]  w_C;
  logic [WIDTH-1:0] w_G, w_P, w_SUM;
  
  //Generate full adders
  genvar i;
  fulladder f0 (i_bit1(i_add1[0]), i_bit2(i_add2[0]),i_carry(w_C[0]), o_sum(w_SUM[0]), o_carry());
endmodule
```

---

```
# ** Error: testbench.sv(13): Module 'fulladder' is not defined.
#  For instance 'f0' at path 'carry_lookahead_adder'
```

The `design.sv` file does not appear to have the `fulladder` module.  You either need to add the module to that file, or (more likely) instruct your simulator to compile the file with the `fulladder` module in it.

---

You also have syntax errors in your module instantiations.  When you use connections by name, you need to use a period before the port name.  For example, you need to use `.i_bit1(i_add1[0])`, etc.:

```
fulladder f0 (.i_bit1(i_add1[0]), .i_bit2(i_add2[0]),.i_carry(w_C[0]), .o_sum(w_SUM[0]), .o_carry());
```